# Using ROME API in Java

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am trying to use the ROME API to read an RSS Feed, but I am struggling on getting the API to work. I have downloaded the ROME 1.0 .jar file, placed it in a folder and to compile my java I do:

javac -cp /path/to/jar/rome-1.0.jar RSSFeed.java

However I am getting messages such as:

RSSFeed.java:6: error: package com.rometools.rome.io does not exist
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;

Answer (score 0):

Package name `com.rometools.rome.io` refers to newer Rome version than 1.0. Replace the 1.0 version with newer version and try again: https://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.9.0

You might also need to add rome-utils, jdom2 and slf4j as dependencies too.